# ¡Qué semana larga! What is the correct idiom for "What a long week!"

Tags: traducción, modismos

'Que semana larga' seems way too literal. Perhaps there is a completely different phrase for expressing a long week/day at work/ etc.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it just needs a [*más*](http://dle.rae.es/?w=m%C3%A1s&o=h) adverb

> Qué día/semana **más** largo.

From the link above:

> 3 (adverbio comparativo). tanto (‖ **pondera la intensidad de la cualidad**  <sub>weighs the intensity of the quality</sub>). ¡Qué casa más bonita tienes!

That helps to convey that this day/week *seems* longer than what it really is (or other regular days/weeks) because it is too boring, there's a lot of work to do, etc.

- Qué casa más bonita - What a beautiful house
- Qué casa más limpia - What a clean house
- Qué semana más larga - What a long week
- Qué vestido más atrevido - What a bold dress
- Qué tipo más insolente - What an insolent guy

Comment: `Qué día/semana más largo.` largo con semana no me suena bien. `Qué día más largo/semana larga.`

Comment: @EmilioGort, tienes razón. "Día" y "semana" tienen géneros distintos y "largo" no concuerda con los dos. Gracias por la puntualización.

Answer (score 7):

In Spanish we would need an intensifier in that sentence:

> Qué semana **más** larga / Qué semana **tan** larga

(I would use the *tan* version, but it is a matter of personal preference).

Nevertheless, we also have a pretty idiomatic expression for that:

> Qué larga se me está haciendo la semana.

If I was to comment with my workmate, I would probably say:

> ¿Aún estamos a miércoles? ¡Qué larga se me está haciendo la semana!

(*Still Wednesday? What a long week!*)

Answer (score 1):

We can use **long** to say that something is exhausting, specially when talking about work.

> - ¡Qué semana cansadora/agotadora/agobiante!
> - ¡Qué semana tan cansadora!

We can also add **tan** to increase the meaning.